# Column span not working properly in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm a python beginner and as the part of my course I am supposed to code a password generator. But I am facing some issues regarding **columnspan**.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Generator...")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

logo_path = "logo.png"

image_holder = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
logo_image = PhotoImage(file=logo_path)
image_holder.create_image(100, 100, image=logo_image)
image_holder.grid(column=1, row=0)

# labels
website = Label(text="Website :")
website.grid(row=1, column=0)

email = Label(text="Email/username :")
email.grid(row=2, column=0)

password = Label(text="Password :")
password.grid(row=3, column=0)

# entry
website_entry = Entry(width=45)
website_entry.grid(row=1, column=1,columnspan=2)

email_entry = Entry(width=45)
email_entry.grid(row=2, column=1,columnspan=2)

password_entry = Entry(width=21)
password_entry.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky="ew")


#buttons
genrate_password = Button(text="Generate Password")
genrate_password.grid(row=3, column=2,sticky="ew")

add_button = Button(text="Add",width=40)
add_button.grid(row=4, column=1,columnspan=2)
window.mainloop()
```

and here is how it is supposed to look like :
[image]

here is my result :
[image]

How can I move the `entry` next to `password label` a little bit right so that it can match the positioning of above two `entries`.

Thank You...

Comment: Try adding `sticky="ew"` to `.grid(...)` for those entry boxes and buttons.

Comment: @acw1668 It has solved the problem but created a new one. It has shifted the entry to a little bit left.

Comment: I don't think it is an issue.  BTW, try using different `padx` values to find the desired output you want. Also I suggested to apply the sticky option to all the entry boxes and buttons, but you didn't.

Comment: @acw1668 It worked when i applied sticky options to all the views(entry and button). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `sticky="ew"` to all the entry boxes and buttons to get the desired output.  Also I would suggest to put the logo at column 0 with `columnspan=3`, so it does put it at the center.

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Generator...")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

logo_path = "images/mypass.png"

image_holder = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
logo_image = PhotoImage(file=logo_path)
image_holder.create_image(100, 100, image=logo_image)
# put at column 0 with columnspan=3 instead
image_holder.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3)

# labels
website = Label(text="Website :")
website.grid(row=1, column=0)

email = Label(text="Email/username :")
email.grid(row=2, column=0)

password = Label(text="Password :")
password.grid(row=3, column=0)

# entry
website_entry = Entry(width=45)
website_entry.grid(row=1, column=1,columnspan=2,sticky="ew") # added sticky

email_entry = Entry(width=45)
email_entry.grid(row=2, column=1,columnspan=2,sticky="ew") # added sticky

password_entry = Entry(width=21)
password_entry.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky="ew") # added sticky


#buttons
genrate_password = Button(text="Generate Password")
genrate_password.grid(row=3, column=2,sticky="ew") # added sticky

add_button = Button(text="Add",width=40)
add_button.grid(row=4, column=1,columnspan=2,sticky="ew") # added sticky
window.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

If you want some paddings between those widgets, you can add `padx` and `pady` options as well:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Generator...")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

logo_path = "images/mypass.png"

image_holder = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
logo_image = PhotoImage(file=logo_path)
image_holder.create_image(100, 100, image=logo_image)
image_holder.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3)

# labels
website = Label(text="Website :")
website.grid(row=1, column=0)

email = Label(text="Email/username :")
email.grid(row=2, column=0)

password = Label(text="Password :")
password.grid(row=3, column=0)

# entry
website_entry = Entry(width=45)
website_entry.grid(row=1, column=1,columnspan=2,sticky="ew",padx=5,pady=3) # added padx and pady

email_entry = Entry(width=45)
email_entry.grid(row=2, column=1,columnspan=2,sticky="ew",padx=5,pady=3) # added padx and pady

password_entry = Entry(width=21)
password_entry.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky="ew",padx=5,pady=3) # added padx and pady


#buttons
genrate_password = Button(text="Generate Password")
genrate_password.grid(row=3, column=2,sticky="ew",padx=5,pady=3) # added padx and pady

add_button = Button(text="Add",width=40)
add_button.grid(row=4, column=1,columnspan=2,sticky="ew",padx=5,pady=3) # added padx and pady
window.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]